# Could not load file or assembly 'x, Version=z.z.z.z, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net

I had copied one dll (name as y.dll) in to bin folder in my asp.net website.

The y.dll internally refers other dll (name as x.dll).

The structure will be as follows,

```
Web Application
   |
   |
  Bin
   |
   |
  y.dll
```

and also

```
 y.dll classlibrary
   |
   |
  Bin
   |
   |
 x.dll
```

while running the application the following exception occured.
Could not load file or assembly 'x, Version=z.z.z.z, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can check the assembly dependency using ildasm.exe. It is installed with the Microsoft SDK.

Should be in a path like: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin